# Delphi: fast stream to sha256 for large file (100 MB)

Tags: delphi

I have a function for generate the sha256 for a stream. This function take around 5 seconds for 100 MB FileStream. Any tips for make it faster?

```
function GetStreamToHashSHA256Hex(const Content: TStream): string;
const
  //ChunkSize = $F000; // 61440
  ChunkSize = 1024*1024; // 1 mb
var
  aHashSHA2:  THashSHA2;
  aBytes:     TBytes;
  aBytesRead: Integer;
begin
  aHashSHA2 := THashSHA2.create;

  SetLength(aBytes, ChunkSize);
  try
    //Content.Seek(0, soBeginning);
    Content.Position := 0;

    repeat
      aBytesRead := Content.Read(aBytes, ChunkSize);
      if (aBytesRead = 0) then Break; // Done
      aHashSHA2.Update(aBytes, aBytesRead);
    until False;

    //Content.Seek(0, soBeginning);
    Content.Position := 0;

    Result := aHashSHA2.HashAsString;
  finally
    aHashSHA2.Reset;
    aBytes := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: on Berlin there is `THashSHA2.GetHashString(const AString: string; AHashVersion: TSHA2Version)`

Comment: Try fastmm32. I have seen that makes a lot of improvements sometimes.

Comment: @jimsweb that might be the case for code that performed a lot of heap allocations but this won't. Also, the default mm in Delphi is FastMM.

Comment: You can try https://github.com/Xor-el/HashLib4Pascal
It comes with benchmark project, on my pc it shows 114 mb/sec for SHA2-256 (Win32, Release).

Comment: You may want to try the MS Crypto implementation which according to the answer is much faster than THashSHA2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43480899/937125

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in this code that can be improved upon. You already read the file in large chunks. The only opportunity to improve performance is in the hash implementation itself.

In other words, you might try alternative hash implementations to see if others are faster. An obvious place to start is with those from the Synopse project.

You should also compare the performance of your code with that obtained using a respectable command line hash program. This will give you a feel for what sort of performance is attainable.

Comment: "*There is nothing in this code that can be improved upon*" - one optimization might be to use a memory mapped file instead, then hash the entire file in one go without having to read it into memory in chunks.

Comment: @remy nah, that won't make any difference

Comment: are you sure? Because I have apps that get a substantial speed boost when using memory mapped files vs traditional disk reads.

Comment: @Remy Sequential disk read of 100MB in 1MB chunks takes basically zero time. Problem is surely crappy hash code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm getting a read time for a 100MB file of 40ms, on a local SSD drive. So no, I don't think that the data access is what is consuming time here.

Comment: Yeah, well, many people (myself included) don't have the luxury of using SSDs, so ...

Comment: Using SSDs is no luxery in 2019

Comment: @Remy What the heck are you using if it takes best part of 5s to read 100MB from your disk? You still on floppies? How can memory mapping help here anyway? It's gotta come off the disk (or the disk cache) at some point. Memory mapping doesn't make disk read times faster.

Comment: @StefanGlienke it is for people (like me) who don't have the money to buy them...

Comment: @StefanGlienke here  in Algeria the price of an SSD is the income of our clients (end users) after one month of hard work, the price of an HDD is the income of a week. So it is really a matter of software acceleration and not hardware if you want to compete.

Comment: I have to agree with David's suggestion about trying some other hashing libraries. And the main reason for this is that `THashSHA2` is a software implementation of hashing algorithm. But since most modern CPU's already have integrated support for hardware accelerated hashing of data using a library that can use that hardware acceleration will give you much better overall performance..